# Should I use one admin email account to join all computers to Azure Ad

Tags: entra-id

I have a scenario where the client has no on-premises AD and wants to use Azure AD. Now my first question is, should I use one account like admin@abc.com to join all the computers to Azure AD and once joined get other users to login with their own email address?

Second question, So, here admin keeps the local admin account and newly signed in user cannot make changes without admin's email account?

Currently only admin@abc.com has global administrator rights in 365.

I couldn't get clear answer anywhere. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now my first question is, should I use one account like admin@abc.com
> to join all the computers to Azure AD and once joined get other users
> to login with their own email address?

Yes, you could do that.

> Second question, So, here admin keeps the local admin account and
> newly signed in user cannot make changes without admin's email
> account?

Yes, that is correct.

> I couldn't get clear answer anywhere.

Have a read of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/assign-local-admin